# Designing asynchronous API with Python's asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, netty, python-asyncio, aio

I used to work with Netty in Java and I really liked it's concepts and the way it does things. Now, I am working on a Python project and I need to design an API that is able to asynchronously perform IO operations over many different transport layers.

I decided to create something similar to Netty. Of course I understand that Netty is very large of a project and I will never be able to mimick it's brilliant features, but I would just like to implement some of its basics on top of Python's asyncio.

Here's what I got so far:

```
from .utility import Next

__all__ = [
    "ChannelHandler", "InboundHandler", "OutboundHandler",
    "Pipeline", "Channel"
]

class ChannelHandler:

    async def connected(self, channel):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    async def raised(self, channel, exception):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    async def disconnected(self, channel):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class InboundHandler:

    async def received(self, channel, data, next):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class OutboundHandler:

    async def sent(self, channel, message, next):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Pipeline:

    def __init__(self, channel, channel_handler, inbound_handlers, outbound_handlers):
        self.channel = channel
        self.channel_handler = channel_handler
        self.inbound_handlers = inbound_handlers
        self.outbound_handlers = outbound_handlers

    async def handle_raise_event(self, exception):
        await self.channel_handler.raised(channel, exception)

    async def handle_receive_event(self, data):
        await Next(self.inbound_handlers).next(self.channel, data)

    async def handle_send_event(self, message):
        await Next(self.outbound_handlers).next(self.channel, message)

class Channel:

    def __init__(self, url, channel_handler, inbound_handlers, outbound_handlers, options={}):
        self.url = url
        self.pipeline = Pipeline(self, channel_handler, inbound_handlers, outbound_handlers)
        self.options = options

    async def connect(self):
        pass

    async def send(self, message):
        pass

    async def disconnect(self):
        pass

async def connect(url, channel_handler, inbound_handlers, outbound_handlers, options={}):
    pass
```

This is the core API module. And here's an example how it should be used:

```
import asyncio
import transport

class DummyChannelHandler:

    async def connected(self, channel):
        print("Connected.")

    async def raised(self, channel, exception):
        print("Error:", exception)
        await channel.disconnect()

    async def disconnected(self, channel):
        print("Disconected.")

class DummyInboundHandler:

    async def received(self, channel, data, next):
        print("Received:", data)

class DummyOutboundHandler:

    async def sent(self, channel, message, next):
        await channel.write(message.encode())

async def main():
    channel = await transport.connect(
        "udp://192.168.20.244:55300",
        DummyChannelHandler(),
        [DummyInboundHandler()],
        [DummyOutboundHandler()]
    )

    await channel.send("Hi!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

As I said, I am very new to asyncio. I would like to ask you about your oppinions and I would really appreciate some advice. Like, is this the way that `asyncio` should be used? Or am I completely missing the point? Could this possibly work? And how about some synchronization problems? I am aware of stuff like locks, queues, but it is unclear to me how I would use those with `asyncio`.

I have no idea if the API is designed right. For example, I am not very sure if the keyword `async` is used in right places. Same goes with `await`.

If you happen to catch something, please leave me a comment, thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome on stackoverflow. Your question is interesting, and imho deserves an answer, but it's way too broad for the kind of QA that is expected on Stack Overflow, because it's a design issue and there will be as many good answers as there will be people to answer it. So I'm voting for closing it ☹

Comment: Yeah, sure, I understand. I was just curious about oppinions of others because at this point, I am really confused. Even after reading some asyncio tutorials, I can't seem to progress with this. If anyone could contribute with a little help or just a different point of view, I think it could help me a lot. But sure, I understand that this is not really a "question".

Comment: I will try to help out, when you say, "able to asynchronously perform IO operations over many different transport layers", do you really mean transports, or do you mean Protocols, I think you mean protocols, otherwise I am a bit confused. Transports are implementations of e.g. UDP, TCP, etc, where Protocols, are used implement communication schemes, handle HTTP traffic, IMAP etc, or custom behavier that you define. An example is the echo server, that is a protocol that just echos the input. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol

Comment: Actually, I mean both. User should be able to specify their protocols using `ChannelHandler`, `InboundHandler` and `OutboundHandler`. However, I still need to implement transport layers like UDP, TCP etc. What I would like to do is use the implementations that `asyncio` already provides and wrap them in the API I proposed above. My problem is that I am not really sure how.